# Can you add queens in production to a control group?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg

I am currently working on a strategy that involves having 4-6 queens in my final army comp (plus a queen for each hatchery). My problem is that whenever I queue up a queen to be produced, I have to go back when she is finished and add her to the control group (making sure she is not the queen I use for injects that I hotkey specifically).

I was wondering if there was a way to add a queen in production to a control group similar to the way you can add any eggs before they hatch to a control group?

Comment: isn't that the same problem with "normal" production structure (all terran and non-warpgate protos units)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You can't** add queens to the group while they are in production.

To make things even worse you can't even set the rally point for them,since queens always spawn directly near the hatchery(in free space) ignoring the rally point.
And since they emerge directly from it,there are no eggs to be grouped.

There already are few [threads](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/2065607764) on blizzard forum where people complain about this issue.

*[Here](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Queen) under "spawn larvae" section there are few tricks on how to use spawn larvae(queen ability) faster,in your case it might help you to select queens and group them a bit faster.*